# How do I make the page refresh in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I want to make  a script like this:

```
window.location = "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyPurchase?assetid=122174821&type=robux&expectedPrice=1"
document.getElementsByClassName('buyButtonClass')[1].click()
```

but I don't know how to make the page refresh and the code start over without it having to manually be entered again
Thanks

By the way it will be running in Google Chrome Dev. tools Console

I tried

```
function blah() {
// window.location = "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyPurchase?
assetid=122174821&type=robux&expectedPrice=1"
document.getElementsByClassName('buyButtonClass')[1].click()
if (some_condition) {
blah() // rerun the code
}
}
```

Output was "undefined", the script did nothing.

The script goes to a link, clicks a button (currently it doesn't click for some reason) then restarts the script (not working)

Comment: are you trying to call the blah() function on button click?

Comment: No I am trying to make it click a button

Comment: Sounds strange, tell us your purpose instead.

Comment: Please give us the big picture, why are you refreshing the page? why do you need to click the button?

Comment: I agree, let's see what your purpose is first.  May want to reconsider the approach / flow.

Comment: It is a bot that presses a buy button on the page, and it refreshes because the buy button might not be there

Comment: wouldnt it be better to check if the button exists, if yes click the button (or) reload the page? I am sorry if I completely misunderstood your question once again (its saturday morning you see :P)

Comment: You need to code your bot server side.  But I am still a little confused.  Is the end goal just to ensure that a particular button exists on your page?  If so, how are you initially creating the button?  With javascript?  I still don't see how refreshing the page would help.

Comment: or are you trying to wait till the page is fully loaded before you click the button? what is the reason button will not be there? is it because page is not yet loaded fully? if yes, try kikuchiyo's answer.

Comment: The goal is to look for the button, if found click, if not refresh.

Comment: The reason the button may not be there is because the page may be different until it is changed by an administrator on the site

Answer (score 1):

setting window.location = ... will refresh the page, but stuff after that will not trigger, because you just refreshed the page including all the javascript.  You can put the code you want to trigger in a $(document).ready(function(){your_code_here}); call and when the page refreshes, it will set up your click event.

Comment: What would the completed script look like?

Comment: Let's focus on the big picture like @Anderson suggested first in the comments to your question above.

Comment: It is a bot that presses a buy button on the page, and it refreshes because the buy button might not be there – Notheir 1 min ago edit